# Operand type clash: x-schema.Array is incompatible with dbo.Array

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL. and have 2 schema in it. Default schema - dbo and another is schema x.

both have set of same set of stored procedures, tables and a custom type called array.

However, when stored proc from schema x tries to access the x.array type it throws following error:

Operand type clash: x.Array is incompatible with dbo.Array

please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

issue was due to the ambiguity and hence deleted the type created in the non dbo schema and instead kept only 1 type which was part of dbo.

and gave EXEC Grant to the TYPE to respective users and it worked.